# Hola, alguien me da una mano? no puedo acceder a la vista usuarios porque no tengo permiso para acceder. 403-error

Tags: php, laravel, permisos, storage, error-403

[image: este es mi código]
[image: Este es mi código]

[![este es mi código, mi controlador y mis rutas]

---

[image: y aqui esta mis carpetas]

y aqui están mis carpetas, soy nuevo usando laravel

Comment: Lectura recomendada: https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/4433/822 Saludos.

Comment: Por favor, aclara tu problema específico o proporciona detalles adicionales para resaltar exactamente lo que necesitas. Tal como está escrito, es difícil saber exactamente qué estás preguntando.

Comment: hola si, pasa lo siguiente: yo cuando quiero acceder a la url users.list en mi navegador aparece el mensaje 403 forbidden "que no tendo permiso para acceder" y la verdad nose como solucionarlo.

Comment: Bienvenid@ a Stack Overflow en español! Te sugiero leer [Cómo preguntar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) para mejorar tu pregunta y que sea mejor recibida. También, aprovechar y [hacer el recorrido](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) para entender mejor cómo funcionamos. Tambien [Un fragmento de código vale más que mil imágenes…](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/3976/92278) e [Historias de terror para programadores](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/2869/92278).

Answer (score 0):

a mi esto me suele ocurrir a menudo en Linux y lo soluciono ejecutando los comandos

```
sudo chmod -R 755 ruta_a_carpeta_proyecto
```

Y luego el comando

```
chown usuariox:grupo ruta_a_carpeta_proyecto
```

En mi caso el usuario es home h grupo es home

Aclaro que esto solo me ha resultado una vez en Linux y espero que sirva de ayuda